# How to get a specific field in MongoDB document

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I am using PyMongo to work with MongoDB database. My aim is to get a specific field from the document. I am using "find_one" and "find" function which return the cursor not the field as such.

Here is a sample document.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "622226e937a677bc5380f10f"
    },
    "name": "test user",
    "place": "test place",
    "descr": "test test test",
    "email": "testuser@testttt.com",
    "pri": "High",
    "date": "2022-03-04",
    "token": "096e9476cad5f1c59e",
    "status": "To-do"
}
```

What query can I use to return say "test user" in string?

Answer (score 1):

Actually `find_one` [returns single document](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#getting-a-single-document-with-find-one).
And you simply can get its field:

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
<..>
user = users.find_one({"_id": ObjectId("622226e937a677bc5380f10f")})
if user:
    return user["name"]
```